# Material-UI Pickers: Display Date as (M, DD, YYYY) -> (April 17, 2019)

Tags: html, date, material-ui

This is the Material-Ui Pickers library: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/datepicker

As you can see it seems it's possible to display the date as a (Month Day) string or as a (MM/DD/YYYY) date however I cannot find anything that would allow me display date as (Month DD, YYYYY) is this possible, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example using moment:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, DatePicker } from 'material-ui-pickers';
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';

class LocalizedUtils extends MomentUtils {
  getDatePickerHeaderText(date) {
    return moment(date).format('ll');
  }
}

function DateLocalizationExample() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={LocalizedUtils}>
      <DatePicker
        clearable
        helperText="moment"
        format="ll"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        clearLabel="vider"
        cancelLabel="annuler"
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

export default DateLocalizationExample;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Material use either Moment.js or Date.fns, you should use the format standard for whichever library you are using. For example, [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) uses `MMMM Do YYYY`

Comment: True, I am using Moment I don't know why I didn't think to look at their documentation. Thank You~

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format` prop to override the format right in text field.

And also you can take advantage of [global format customization](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/formats) guide. It allows changing the formats directly in date/time picker modal dialog.